# LyX Beamer Author Names Get Cut Off

Tags: beamer, lyx

I am using LyX and the beamer template to write presentation slides for a conference paper, which has three authors. This is not a problem, until I notice that the third name gets cut off from the bottom left corner of the slide (see screenshot below). How can I fix this?

[image]

Technical Details:

- Mac OS X 10.7.5 (Lion)
- LaTeX Version 2.0 (build 150)
- LyX Version 2.0.6

Comment: Which `beamer` theme are you using?

Comment: The one in the default `beamer-conference-ornate-20min.lyx`

Comment: And do you want to keep the name of the three authors in the footline of all your slides?

Comment: Preferably. Especially, since the space exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to reduce the font used for authors in the footline; you can try adding to the preamble the following:

```
\setbeamerfont{author in head/foot}{size=\tiny}
```

or (for even smaller size):

```
\setbeamerfont{author in head/foot}{size=\fontsize{4}{4.8}\selectfont}
```